# Why did SE choose an already-existing cryptocoin?

Tags: discussion, unicoins, april-fools

Unicoin looks like an actual coin that was launched on New Years', based on [forum posts](https://cryptocointalk.com/topic/2687-unicoin-unic-information/) from Dec 31. Unicoin.info has been registered since Dec 30. Have they really been building the backstory for months, or is this another group?

Also, is this a not-so-subtle jab at [Arscoin](http://arstechnica.com/business/2014/03/behold-arscoin-our-own-custom-cryptocurrency/)?

Comment: It's another group I think. One day there will be an epic battle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that that other Unicoin seems to be considered pretty dead by the cryptocoin community, and that the name is just so obviously right for us, we decided to not worry about it. And should it ever revive, it can have the name back for the remainder of the year. Random trivia: Until we decided on the name, the working title was "StaxCoin".

Comment: Wafflecoins would have worked as well. At least on MSO.